# Allocation of design points in an experiment

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, experiment-design

I would like some hints with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

An experimenter wants to design an experiment for estimating the rate of change in a dependent variable Y as an independent variable X is changed. He is convinced from previous experience that the relationship is linear in the region of interest, between X=0 and X=11. He has enough resources to obtain 12 observations. Use $\sigma{^2}$($\hat\beta_1$}) to show the researcher the best allocation of the design points.

I am not really sure how to use the variance.

Comment: The "best" allocation will be one that minimizes the estimation variance of the rate of change. You should be able to express that estimation variance in terms of the values of $X$ chosen in the experiment. (It doesn't depend on the *observed* values of $Y$ at all.) Although that gives a twelve-dimensional optimization problem, an acute guess will suggest how to solve it.

Comment: I know that the variance of beta 1 is equal to the variance of Y divided by the sum of the X's squared minus the squared sum of the X's over the number of observations. Am I supposed to make an assumption about the X's?

Comment: I believe you have all the information you need about the $X$'s.  Remember, the "allocation of the design points" amounts to *your specification* of what those $12$ values will be. If you set any of them beyond the interval $[0,11]$, you cannot rely on the linearity assumption, which means you won't be able to use such values in your model. Consequently, you know that (a) you may specify *up to* $12$ useful values of $X$ between $0$ and $11$ (inclusive) and that (b) subject to that constraint, you would like the estimation variance of $\hat\beta$ to be as small as possible.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is to choose all of the X's to be the integer values along the interval [0,11].

Comment: Optimization consists of *varying* whatever you can think of to see whether you can do better.  BTW, I don't see anything in the question that actually requires you to set the values of $X$ to integers.

Comment: No, nothing requires me to set the values to integers.